# how to test that service object is initialized with the correct params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a Rails app I have a background job that calls a service object

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform( obj_id )
    return unless object = Object.find(obj_id)
    MyServiceObject.new(object).call
  end
end
```

I can test that the job calls the service object as follows:

```
describe MyJob, type: :job do
  let(:object) { create :object }
  it 'calls MyServiceObject' do
    expect_any_instance_of(MyServiceObject).to receive(:call)
    MyJob.new.perform(object)
  end
end
```

But how to test that the job initializes the service object with the correct params?

```
describe MyJob, type: :job do
  let(:object) { create :object }
  it 'initializes MyServiceObject with object' do
    expect( MyServiceObject.new(object) ).to receive(:call)
    MyJob.new.perform(object)
  end
end
```

I want to achieve something like above, but this fails with `expects 1 but received 0`.

What is the correct way to test a class is initialized correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently my fix to Adilbiy's answer was turned down, so here's my updated answer:

```
describe MyJob, type: :job do
  let(:object) { create :object }
  it 'initializes MyServiceObject with object' do
    so = MyServiceObject.new(object)
    expect(MyServiceObject).to receive(:new).with(object).and_return(so)
    MyJob.new.perform(object)
  end
end
```

By mocking `MyServiceObject.new` with `expect(MyServiceObject).to receive(:new).with(object)`, you overwrite the original implementation. However, for `MyJob#perform` to work, we need `MyServiceObject.new` to return an object - which you can do with `.and_return(...)`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest following test:

```
describe MyJob, type: :job do
  let(:object) { create :object }
  it 'initializes MyServiceObject with object' do
    expect( MyServiceObject).to receive(:new).with(object)
    MyJob.new.perform(object)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @adilbiy, I had thought the same. However, this returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for nil:NilClass`. It causes my MyServiceObject to be initialized with no params for some reason. Is this 100% the correct approach? My code appears to be working correctly outside of tests, so trying to figure out where the issue lies.

Comment: I fixed the example (added `and_return`; in review now), this should fix the Problem.

Comment: thanks @mhutter, but I don't see your edit. Could you post again?